# Can I create a foreign key from an ENUM type column?

Tags: sql, database, enums, reference

I have the following code, and I want to create a foreign reference between the columns labeles "tipo":

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS preferencias(
DNIusuario VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
tipo ENUM("Paseo", "Gastronomia", "Deporte interior", "Deporte exterior", "Cultura", "Arte", "Naturaleza", "Cine", "Musica", "Fiesta", "Terraceo", "Compras") NOT NULL,
obligatoria BIT,
ultimaactividad DATE,
PRIMARY KEY(DNIusuario,tipo), 
FOREIGN KEY (DNIusuario) REFERENCES registros(DNI)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS citas(
IDcita INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
fechacita DATE,
lugarcita VARCHAR(25),
tipo ENUM("Paseo", "Gastronomia", "Deporte interior", "Deporte exterior", "Cultura", "Arte", "Naturaleza", "Cine", "Musica", "Fiesta", "Terraceo", "Compras") NOT NULL,
resultado SET("1","2","3","4","5"),
FOREIGN KEY (tipo) REFERENCES preferencias(tipo)
);
```

When creating the tables individually (without the foreign key constraint), they work just fine. All my other foreign references in this db work fine too. However, when trying to create a foreign key constraint for ENUM type values, I get the following error message:

ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

So, my dear friends... what do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you declare it correctly.  That means that you reference the entire primary key so you need `DNIusuario`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS citas(
    IDcita INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fechacita DATE,
    lugarcita VARCHAR(25),
    tipo ENUM("Paseo", "Gastronomia", "Deporte interior", "Deporte exterior", "Cultura", "Arte", "Naturaleza", "Cine", "Musica", "Fiesta", "Terraceo", "Compras") NOT NULL,
    resultado SET("1","2","3","4","5"),
    DNIusuario VARCHAR(9),
    FOREIGN KEY (DNIusuario, tipo) REFERENCES preferencias(DNIusuario, tipo)
);
```

That said, I would never actually recommend doing this.  Maintaining enums is fraught enough within one table without having them in multiple tables.  I would advise you to do the following:

- Create a table `tipos` with an auto-incremented column and the name of the `tipo` -- and perhaps other information.
- Change your existing tables so they have an auto-incremented column to serve as the primary key.  Then use that for references from other tables.
- Also, use single quotes for string constants, not double quotes.  Single quotes are the database standard and in many databases, double quotes are for quoting identifiers not delimiting strings.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much! Unfortunately, this brings me to the next problem... citas needs to be able to reference more than one value for DNIusuario, so I had  the following code for a third table to bring it all together:
 {CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS participantes(
 DNIusuario VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
 IDcita INT,
 PRIMARY KEY(DNIusuario, IDcita),
 FOREIGN KEY (DNIusuario) REFERENCES registros(DNI),
 FOREIGN KEY (IDcita) REFERENCES citas(IDcita)
);}

Comment: Allright, good point on your clarification. Didn't notice it. I'll mess around with it and see if I can get it to work. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jools . . . This answers the question you have here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.